# Why I'm always getting ModelMapper is Null when ı use @NoArgsConstructor in Manager Classes in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, lombok, modelmapper

as an example

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JobPositionManager implements JobPositionService {
    private ModelMapperService modelMapperService;

    public Result add(CreateJobPositionRequest jobPositionRequest) {
        JobPosition position = this.modelMapperService.forRequest().map(jobPositionRequest, JobPosition.class);
        this.positionRepository.save(position);
        return new SuccessResult("--!");
}
```

and there is this line on my modelmapper class

```
   .setSkipNullEnabled(true)
```

by the way, there are other annotations of course, like
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor

I had added @NoArgsConstructor for some reason and forgot to delete it then I tried adding new object but this annotation gives me error and ı wonder why

Comment: what other result did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

When ever you declare services, repositories and other elements in your spring-boot application, you need to wire it properly otherwise it's juste an empty attribute.

For that you need the @Autowired annotation over the attributes you want to declare.
In this case :

```
@Autowired
private ModelMapperService modelMapperService;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: probably the OP means to say that the expected behavior on their side is that the noArgsConstructor will instantiate the field. Since it's not sure ModelMapperService can be autowired, this on itself may not be the best answer.

Comment: @AllArgsConstructor is sufficient for this. it's ok when i just use this explanation but i'm just curious about the answer to the question i asked

Comment: @Stultuske ı see 